# Route mouse-event to underlying control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with a grid whith just one row and one column. To this column I add a combobox which fills the whole space of the column. Now I want to put a canvas-element over the combobox in the left corner. Until here everything works fine.

The code:

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource Flat}" SelectionChanged="ColorSelectionChanged" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCol, UpdateSourceTrigger}"\>
<Canvas Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="25"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{Binding SelectedColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

If I move the mouse over this conrtrol I only get the selection of the combobox if I'm not over the canvas. How can I route the mouse-events from the canvas to the combobox?

Comment: Try to set the property IsHitTest = false on your canvas or was it IsHitTestVisible = false. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the canvas is just for show, you can turn off hit testing `IsHitTestVisible="false"` on the `canvas`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx